# Is there a way to copy/output the decoded data to a surface/anativewindow manually?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Good day,

Im currently investigating video rendering processes in android.
We will be using native codes for my project, specifically OpenGL.

So far my investigation suggest passing directly a surface to the decoder.
Heres the sample
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-codec

I wanted to have more control. After decoding I want to output/copy manually the decoded data to a native window/ surface.

Here's my plan so far.

Get Surface from Java -> create native windows from surface -> copy data to native window(if possible) -> use opengl and egl to render the video data.

P.S (Im new to android, no experience especially in android native)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure your `MediaCodec`'s output surface to `SurfaceTexture` (aka GL consumer) instead of copying manually.

[MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec)

[SurfaceTexture](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-st)